# How to use tinyMCE into sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, tinymce, sonata-admin

I want for all my entity properties type "text" to show a html editor(preferably tinyMCE) in the forms to create and edit.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the text input is the best way (and possible) to represent your text editor over the textarea element using TinyMCE. Here it goes how you do it:

```
->add('myText', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce', 'tinymce'=>'{"theme":"simple"}')));
```

You can later include TinyMCE dependencies by adding a custom template for this field with its *template* option (although it would be recommended to add them inside the `<head>` of the page)

Answer (score 0):

hi first install tinycme editor bundle in your project for this please see  [this page](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle)
after that for using in sonata admin see [this issue](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle/issues/68)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).